# Dynamic register to broadcast receiver not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

When I'm setting my broadcast receiver as anonymous class his never called 
but when I'm setting it as class and declare it on android manifest its work fine

i want the ability of register and unregister the broadcast receiver dynamically
why its won't working

here is my code:

```
public class AppChangedProbe extends Probe.Base implements Probe.ContinuousProbe{

private BroadcastReceiver appReceiver;


@Override
protected void onEnable() {

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();


    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED);


    appReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED))
                Logger.i(getClass(), "App Removed");

            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED))
                Logger.i(getClass(),"App Updated");

            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED))
                Logger.i(getClass(),"App Added");
        }
    };

    getContext().registerReceiver(appReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onDisable() {
    getContext().unregisterReceiver(appReceiver);
}

@Override
protected boolean isWakeLockedWhileRunning() {
    return false;
}
```

}

the Probe.Base and Probe.ContinuousProbe are FUNF project jars.

i set this permissions on the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_ADDED" />
```

when i use the broadcast receiver as class its work

here is the code that work:

```
public class AppChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED))
        Logger.i(getClass(),"App Removed");

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED))
        Logger.i(getClass(),"App Updated");

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED))
        Logger.i(getClass(),"App Added");

}
```

}

and in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name =".sensors.EventBaseProbes.AppChangedReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
            <data android:scheme="package"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

the occurred is that when i use other actions its work in both ways.

for example if i replace the filter on the example to this filter

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
```

the receiver works fine and get called when the screen is on

are they 2 kinds of action:
 1) need to be declared on manifest
 2) don't need to be declared on manifest

Answer (score 5):

I have been dealing with the same problem recently. Here is how you should do.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED);
filter.addDataScheme("package");
```

Since you have `<data android:scheme="package"/>` inside your `AndroidManifest` file. You should have it  programatically too. Otherwise it won't work.

And lastly, you don't have to add any permission. These Broadcasts doesn't require permission.